# Convert downloaded YouTube videos (downloaded with youtube-dl) to audio-only, with no loss?

Tags: sound, youtube, ogg-vorbis, transcode, youtube-dl

If one downloads videos from YouTube using `youtube-dl`, they get `.mp4` files which are a `ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2`.

Can these files be converted to audio-only, ideally with no quality loss?
The goal is to save space by throwing out the unneeded visual part.

Comment: even after you convert it to mp3, I don't think the size will change see my  question from yesterday http://askubuntu.com/questions/421777/is-it-possible-to-restore-the-original-quality-of-a-youtube-video-after-download

Comment: Voting to keep this open, as the answers and question here are superior, and with a slightly different focus.

Comment: Voting to close. There is already [a question about How to extract audio from video files](http://askubuntu.com/q/80954/62483).

Answer (score 10):

You can convert to audio only formats using youtube-dl itself, although it still downloads the video and then converts it.

To do this, use `-x` or `--extract-audio` to the command, for example:

```
youtube-dl -x 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0iyeUcFKRv4&feature=c4-overview&list=UU1KPy3cAAj0i0RIFC_SzjMg'
```

Comment: "youtube-dl -f bestaudio <url>" also works

Answer (score 8):

You can convert existing downloaded files using ffmpeg from the command-line

```
ffmpeg -i "input file.mp4" -acodec copy "output file.aac"
```

The "acodec copy" part is the bit that doesn't change the audio stream.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[YouTube Center](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter) is excellent user script, which works accross browsers, doesn't involve bloating your OS with ton of Youtube downloaders *unless* you're a strictly **320 kbps** person for your audio files. Besides, you have [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) at your disposal which involves bit of a manual work but will do exactly what you want. :)

Answer (score 4):

A command line alternative to download and immediately convert to a desired format is to send a file downloaded with [**cclive**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cclive) [image: Install cclive] to **avconv** with the cclive option `--exec`.

#### Examples:

1. Download video, then extract the audio track to keep the original encoding:

   ```
   cclive -f best <videolink> --exec "avconv -i '%n' -acodec copy <name>.<extension>"
   ```

   - *needs `<extension>` to be in the same format as the source audio format (e.g. `aac`)*
2. Download video, then convert audio to mp3 (or any other supported audio codec):

   ```
   cclive -f best <videolink> --exec "avconv -i '%n' -acodec lbmp3lame -b:a 256k <name>.mp3"
   ```

   - *will download and convert to 256 kb/s mp3.*
3. Download video, copy audio, and delete video:

   ```
   cclive -f best <videolink> --exec "avconv -i '%n' -acodec copy <name>.aac" --exec "rm '%n'"
   ```

   - *will delete the downloaded video after audio extraction.*

We are quite versatile to convert to any audio codec avconv can encode, and this will also work on download sites other than YouTube.

**Note for cclive >= 0.7.12 in Ubuntu >= 13.10:**
*Option `-f` was replaced by option `-s`. Give option `-s best` for best available encoding, `-s <ID>` for any other encoding as can be listed with `cclive -S <URL>`.*

Answer (score 3):

`youtube-dl --help` explains how:

```
  Post-processing Options:
    -x, --extract-audio              convert video files to audio-only
                                     files (requires ffmpeg or avconv and
                                     ffprobe or avprobe)
    --audio-format FORMAT            "best", "aac", "vorbis", "mp3", "m4a",
                                     "opus", or "wav"; best by default
    --audio-quality QUALITY          ffmpeg/avconv audio quality
                                     specification, insert a value between
                                     0 (better) and 9 (worse) for VBR or a
                                     specific bitrate like 128K (default 5)
```

Also look at my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/420920/248158) which describes how to download just the audio instead of *first* downloading the video+audio and *then* discarding the video which is just wasteful.